# Not able to see stack trace using windbg or Visual studio 2012/13

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windbg, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

Even after giving correct PDB symbols I cant see stack trace where it can tell me function calls. Stack text only shows msvcr120. Also this crash occurs on customer machine only. I am wondering if something is missing wrt msvcr120 which we need to install. This is what I can see in windbg:

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00007fffc113dd27 (msvcr120+0x000000000006dd27)
   ExceptionCode: c0000409 (Security check failure or stack buffer overrun)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000005

CONTEXT:  0000000000000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
rax=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=00007fffc113dd27 rsp=000000e40cd261c0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa r12=000000e40c3076b0 r13=0000000000000000
r14=000000000000005c r15=000000e40c3051d0
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
msvcr120+0x6dd27:
00007fff`c113dd27 cd29            int     29h

PROCESS_NAME:  <removed>

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000409 - The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000409 - The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000005

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APP:  <removed>

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000005188

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_ARG_FAILURE_SEHOP

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_ARG_FAILURE_SEHOP

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_ARG_FAILURE_SEHOP

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000000000000 to 00007fffc113dd27

STACK_TEXT:  
000000e4`0cd261c0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa 00000000`00000000 : msvcr120+0x6dd27


STACK_COMMAND:  ~5s; .ecxr ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
msvcr120+6dd27
00007fff`c113dd27 cd29            int     29h

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  msvcr120+6dd27

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: msvcr120

IMAGE_NAME:  msvcr120.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  524f83ff

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_ARG_FAILURE_SEHOP_c0000409_msvcr120.dll!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_ARG_FAILURE_SEHOP_msvcr120+6dd27

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:invalid_arg_failure_sehop_c0000409_msvcr120.dll!unknown

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {6c95a838-d91e-9c26-c623-f4edddde2886}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0:005> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
000000e4`0cd261c0 00000000`00000000 msvcr120+0x6dd27
```

(Btw I have tried every possible suggestion I found to get stack trace on stackoverflow and other places before asking question)

Comment: please try an older Windbg version. I've currently looked at a dmp with a new Windbg and old Windbg version the new version only shows crap. Microsoft is currently investigating why the new Windbg shows only garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output above, you do not have valid symbols for `msvcr120`. The first step is to try and get those. If you can't get the symbols, or you do get them and still can't get a good stack trace, then you should use [`dqs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540455.aspx) and try to manually walk the stack.